# Implementing Table Value Parameters in Stored Procedures for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having difficulty understanding the implementation of table-valued parameter that is required as an input parameter for a stored procedure. I am required to create a stored procedure based on the following requirement:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2EDY.jpg

It clearly states that I am required to create a stored procedure that is named `usp_createPackage` with input and output parameters. Prior to this, I have created the tables that are needed for these stored procedures below:

```
CREATE TABLE ServicePackage
(
    servicePackageID    VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    name                VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    description         VARCHAR (50),
    startDate           DATE NOT NULL,
    endDate             DATE ,
    advertisePrice      DECIMAL (6,2) NOT NULL,
    inclusion           VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    exclusion           VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    status              VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    serviceID           VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    staffID             VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(servicePackageID),
    FOREIGN KEY (serviceID) 
         REFERENCES ServiceItem (serviceID)
              ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,                                                  
    FOREIGN KEY (staffID) 
         REFERENCES Staff (staffID)
              ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
);
```

The table for service items (for the 2nd input parameters requiring TPV), has the following table and code created:

```
CREATE TABLE ServiceItemInPackage
(
    serviceID           VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    servicePackageID    VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    qty                 INT NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY (serviceID, servicePackageID),
    FOREIGN KEY (serviceID) 
         REFERENCES ServiceItem (serviceID)
              ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,                                                   
    FOREIGN KEY (servicePackageID) 
         REFERENCES ServicePackage (servicePackageID)
);
```

So far, the stored procedure which I am creating, lacks the 2nd parameter which requires TPV, and I have not implemented what happens after begin:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_createPackage
    @name VARCHAR(50),
    @description VARCHAR(50),
    @startDate DATE,
    @endDate DATE,
    @advertisePrice DECIMAL (6,2),
    @staffID VARCHAR(10),
    @servicePackageID VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
```

Can I ask, how do I create a stored procedure with TPV in, and what am I missing to achieve the goal in the imgur?

Comment: Do you remember the instructor talking about creating and using a user defined type? This is what you need to use. You create a type as a table with a number of columns. Short of doing your whole assignment for you there isn't much to be added. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+user+defined+table+type&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: I will take note of that.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) which includes an example. You don't create a table, you create a user-defined table **type**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a User Defined Table Type that represents the table you want to pass to the stored procedure. Once the type is defined, you can then use that type for the stored procedure parameter. Microsoft's documentation on this is a good start.

Comment: I am sorry for being new to the User Defined Table Type. I understood from my read up is that it allows the inclusion of 2 or more parameters into one. User defined table type would be useful for adding the 2nd input parameter into the CREATE PROCEDURE?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain clearly: you were correct about using a **Table Value Parameter**. To use a TVP, the first step is to create a _User Defined Table Type_ in order to specify the table that will be passed in via the parameter. See: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Comment: Understood. I will look into it to see how a TPV would help achieve my goals. The main consensus is that I have to create a table type, not the table. Does the table type values equates with the table values, or the names can be different?

Comment: The table type values can be anything; you need to declare a variable of that type, insert data into that table and then pass the variable to the stored proc. The type columns don't necessarily have to match any physical table columns.